# The prop `Email`and 'Phone' is marked as required in `Contacts`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my app.js file :-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contacts from "./components/Contacts";
import Header from "./components/Header";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header branding="Contact Manager" />
        <div className="container">
          <Contacts />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my Contacts.js file is as follows:-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contact from "./Contact";

class Contacts extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      contacts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John Doe",
          email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
          phone: "555-555-5555"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jay Smith",
          email: "jSmith@gmail.com",
          phone: "555-555-5556"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Gary Gray",
          email: "Ggray@gmail.com",
          phone: "555-555-5557"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {contacts.map(contact => (
          <Contact
            name={contact.name}
            email={contact.email}
            phone={contact.phone}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Contacts;
```

So, I am importing my Contacts.js in my App.js and the code compiles successfully however it does not return the E-mail and Phone option just name. It compiles successfully however when I go to the console window it says:  The prop `Email`and 'Phone' is marked as required in `Contacts`, but its value is `undefined`. What should I correct?

Comment: try changing the state declaration of Contacts to something different (e.g. contacts) from your class name Contacts.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what i did, just changed my contacts.js to contact.js and declared everything again. It worked well after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me,

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/6L8oumsc/5/)

```
class Contact  extends React.Component{

      render() {
          let { name, email, phone } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
              <div>{name}</div>
              <div>{email}</div>
              <div>{phone}</div>
              <div>------------------</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Hello extends React.Component {
         constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          Contacts: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "John Doe",
              email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
              phone: "555-555-5555"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Jay Smith",
              email: "jSmith@gmail.com",
              phone: "555-555-5556"
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: "Gary Gray",
              email: "Ggray@gmail.com",
              phone: "555-555-5557"
            }
          ]
        };
      }
      render() {
        const { Contacts } = this.state;
           return (
          <div>
            {Contacts.map(contact => (
              <Contact
                name={contact.name}
                email={contact.email}
                phone={contact.phone}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello name="World" />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! yeah i figured out what i was doing wrong!! I had a contact.js file and a contacts.js file. I was importing from contact.js and the e-mail and phone was not declared in it. Much appreciated.